# How to solve this using 2's compliment?

Tags: java, binary, twos-complement

```
-19 - 25
```

I got `-19` being 1101101 and `-25 = 1100110`

I know the answer is `-44` which is `1010100` in binary but I can't figure out how to get it using the `-19 -25`.

Comment: 2's compliment? Is that like "my, aren't you looking binary today"? :)

Comment: How about [`Integer#toBinaryString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)

Comment: All your numbers are wrong, as they only have 7 bits, so none of them are proper negative 2's complement numbers (if you imagine that you just dropped a leading zero).

Answer (score 1):

Your -25 should be `1100111` instead of `1100110`. Than you can solve it with an logical &:

```
-19: 1101101 -> 19: 0010011 
-25: 1100111 -> 25: 0011001
-44: 1010100 -> 44: 0101100
```